# UISearchController Push Segue not finding SourceController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue, uisearchcontroller

Please, I have tried everything I can google! Image Provided Below!

I have a main 'ProgramTableViewController' which is a TableView that is populated with an Array of data. I have created a UISearchController (SearchResultsTableViewController) that is presented in code on top of the ProgramTableViewController to search through the array. Once I click on a tableview selected row in the SearchResultsTableView for it to Push Segue to a third 'AboutViewController' that is set up to populate all the data from the array to show all the details of said data. When you segue from the ProgramTableViewController to AboutViewController, it works fine. When you try it from the SearchResultsTableViewController is crashes the app with this error code: **"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'aboutViewTwo'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'"**

I have embedded the SearchResultsTableViewController in a Navigation Controller, didn't fix anything. If I modally do the segue, it half works. Doesn't show nav bar or tab bar and fails when you click on some of the buttons in that AboutViewController.

***(In ProgramViewController)***

## pragma mark - Navigation

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
// Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
// Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AboutView"] || [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"AboutView2"]) {
    
        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        AboutViewController *aboutVwController = [segue destinationViewController];
        EventList *obj  =   [arrayEventList objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
        aboutVwController.eventObj  =   obj;
}
}
```

## pragma mark - Search Events

```
- (UISearchController *)controller {

    if (!_controller) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        SearchResultsTableViewController *resultsController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SearchResults"];
        _controller = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:resultsController];
        _controller.searchResultsUpdater = self;
}
    return _controller;
}
```

## pragma mark - Search Results Updater

```
-(void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

    self.results = nil;
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"eventName contains [cd] %@", self.controller.searchBar.text];
    //NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains [cd] %@", self.controller.searchBar.text];
    self.results = [self->arrayEventList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
}
- (IBAction)searchButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:self.controller animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

***(In SearchResultsTableViewController)***

## pragma mark - Navigation

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"aboutViewTwo"]) {
        NSIndexPath *selectedRowIndex = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        AboutViewController *aboutVwController = [segue destinationViewController];
        EventList *obj  =   [_searchResults objectAtIndex:selectedRowIndex.row];
        aboutVwController.eventObj  =   obj;
}
}
```

[image: StoryBoard Layout]

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is your `SearchResultsTableViewController` embedded with a `NavigationController`? The `error` says it all : ***Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.***

Comment: Yes, I don't know if it is in that picture but I have tried to embed the SearchResultsTableViewController into the NavigationController, both an established one and a brand new one, neither worked.

Answer (score 0):

Change the segue from `Push` to `Modal`.

(Or otherwise, embed the source controller of the segue into a UINavigationController.)

You can only use a `Push` segue within a navigation stack managed by a UINavigationController.

Comment: I have changed it to Modal, it pulls the page and the correct data but the Nav bar at the top and the Tab bar at the bottom do not show. Also, if you click on a button, it'll crash the app.

I also embedded the source controller into a UINavigationController and it literally changed nothing. At all.